# Setting a state variable using another state variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state variable minSearchDate which retrieves a date, populated by the getMinSearchDate function with a call to the setter.

This works fine, with minSearchDate being rendered in the view..

However, my issue is using the state variable minSearchDate to populate another state variable: searchDateFrom. In this case, undefined is always being returned probably because minSearchDate in this instance is either undefined or not accessible.

Why would that be the case?

```
const [minSearchDate, setMinSearchDate] = useState<string>("");

useEffect(() => {
    getMinSearchDate();
}, []);

const getMinSearchDate = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if (doGetMinSearchDate) {
        await doGetMinSearchDate().then(async ({ minDate }) => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setMinSearchDate(minDate);
        });
    }
};

const [searchDateFrom, setSearchDateFrom] = useState(
    dateFromQueryString
        ? new Date(JSON.parse(dateFromQueryString))
        : minSearchDate
        ? new Date(JSON.parse(minSearchDate))
        : undefined
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because the initial state is only evaluated upon the first render of your component. Since `minSearchDate` is updated in an `async` function, it's going to be undefined upon initial render.

You could use `useEffect` to listen for updates to `minSearchDate` and update `searchDateFrom` accordingly:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSearchDateFrom(
    dateFromQueryString
        ? new Date(JSON.parse(dateFromQueryString))
        : minSearchDate
        ? new Date(JSON.parse(minSearchDate))
        : undefined
  )
}, [minSearchDate, dateFromQueryString])
```

This way any time `minSearchDate` is updated, you reprocess `searchDateFrom`.

You didn't show `dateFromQueryString` in your code but I assumed it is a stateful variable, if it's not, you can omit that from the `useEffect` dependency array.

**Alternatively**, you could tweak your current useEffect and getMinSearchDate func to perform this update without another `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(doGetMinSearchDate) {
       getMinSearchDate();
    }

}, [doGetMinSearchDate]);


const setSearchDateFrom = (minDate) => setSearchDateFrom(
    dateFromQueryString
        ? new Date(JSON.parse(dateFromQueryString))
        : minDate
        ? new Date(JSON.parse(minDate))
        : undefined
  )

const getMinSearchDate = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await doGetMinSearchDate().then(async ({ minDate }) => {
       setIsLoading(false);
       setMinSearchDate(minDate);
       setSearchDateFrom(minDate);
    });
    
};
```

I'd argue that this is the preferred approach since you don't need to introduce another `useEffect` and can handle all updates as a consequence/outcome of 1 api call.

Note that in your example, you didn't include `doGetMinSearchDate` in your `useEffect` which once again will not work if that variable is stateful (which is why I included it above).

Comment: Thanks. I worked it out using the second option.